# Delete last elements of column with numbering

Tags: r

My dataframe has a column with consecutive numberings varying between 1 and 20 elements (here 1-4):

```
df <-
numbering col_2 col_3
 1         h     t
 2         t     h
 3         h     t
 1         t     t
 2         h     t
 1         f     h
 2         h     h
 3         h     t
 4         h     h
 1         h     t
```

I need to remove every last row of a consecuitve numbering to get

```
numbering col_2 col_3
 1         h     t
 2         t     h
 1         t     t
 1         f     h
 2         h     h
 3         h     t
 1         h     t
```

Thx

Answer (score 3):

We can create a goruping variable based on the occurrence of 1, then `slice` to remove the last row and keep it if there is only a single row

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(grp = cumsum(numbering == 1)) %>% 
  slice(if(n() == 1) 1 else -n())
```

---

Or use `group_map` to filter the rows

```
df %>% 
   group_by(grp = cumsum(numbering == 1)) %>% 
   group_map(~ if(nrow(.x) ==1) .x else head(.x,-1L)) %>%
   ungroup %>%
   select(-grp)
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(numbering = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
   4L, 1L), col_2 = c("h", "t", "h", "t", "h", "f", "h", "h", "h", 
 "h"), col_3 = c("t", "h", "t", "t", "t", "h", "h", "t", "h", 
 "t")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L))
```

Comment: Thank you...somehow it doesn't work in my df? I can't really figure out why?

Comment: @IskandarThePupsi  Would be great if you can give more info regarding what you are getting etc.  and also a `dput` of a small example that shows the issue would make it easier for others to understand